# How can I find out which data type is correct to store a given integer in Java?

Tags: java, types

Suppose I have been given a number and asked to find out which data type is suitable for storing it. For instance suppose, if the number is *741*, then it can be stored in **short**, **int**, as well as **long** data types. However, if the number entered is huge say, *-100000000000000*, then it can be stored only in **long** data type. Depending on the number entered by the user, I need to provide all possible data types that can be used to store it.

PS: this is a problem that is given on the Hackerrank platform with Java Datatypes.
Problem link:- https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-datatypes/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&isFullScreen=false

Comment: I would build a table that contains the min and max values for each type you want to consider.  Start with an empty list.  Then just iterate over the table and test if the number in question fits within the range of each type.  If you find that it fits, then add the name of that type to the list.  You can use the constants provided by Java...`Integer.MIN_VALUE`, `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, etc.  If you want to be really clever, you can include `BigDecimal` in every list.  It can contain a number of any size and precesion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the primitive data types *wrappers* , they all contain a constant value with the max and min value they can hold up.

They are:

```
Byte.MIN_VALUE; //-128

Byte.MAX_VALUE; //127

Short.MIN_VALUE; //-32768

Short.MAX_VALUE; //32767

Integer.MIN_VALUE; //0x80000000

Integer.MAX_VALUE; //0x7fffffff

Long.MIN_VALUE; //0x8000000000000000L

Long.MAX_VALUE; //0x7fffffffffffffffL
```

Here's my solution:

```
    long n = 0;
    try {
        n = new Scanner(System.in).nextLong();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) { //we're expecting just numbers anyway
        System.out.println("doesn't fit anywhere");
    }
    
    if (n > 0) {
        //since n is positive,
        //first let's evaluate if it's not too big to fit in a byte data type
        if (n <= Byte.MAX_VALUE) System.out.println("fits in a byte");
        
        //now let's evaluate if n is not too big to fit in a short data type
        if (n <= Short.MAX_VALUE) System.out.println("fits in a short");
        
        //now let's evaluate if n is not too big to fit in an int data type
        if (n <= Integer.MAX_VALUE) System.out.println("fits in an int");
        
        
    } else {
        //similar code for negative numbers
        if (n >= Byte.MIN_VALUE) System.out.println("fits in a byte");
        if (n >= Short.MIN_VALUE) System.out.println("fits in a short");
        if (n >= Integer.MIN_VALUE) System.out.println("fits in an int");
    }
    //well, since we already verified n doesn´t overtake a long with try block
    // n will always fit in a long
    System.out.println("fits in a long");
```